# Windows XP slower to read text files at startup in C++; prefetch?

Tags: c++, file-io, filesystems, windows-xp, prefetch

I have an application that is written in C++, Visual Studio 2005 running exclusively in Windows XP. 
When the application is launched it read a large number (> 20000) of text files (.nfo) which contain XML. 
Each file is 800bytes.

When the application is launched after a cold reboot, it takes 10 minutes to read the files. 
However, if I close it and relaunch it, it only takes 10 seconds to read them. If I do a warm reboot, it also takes 10 seconds.
If I clear the cache using the cacheset utility, it also takes 10 seconds to read the files. 
If I do a cold reboot of the computer, don't touch the computer for 2 hours, launch the application, it still takes 10 minutes to launch.

I uses basic function from the standard library (std) to open/read/close the files.

I believe that the problem does not come directly from the implementation of the application but from Windows XP.

My current focus is given to Windows XP's Prefetcher. My application has a .pf file located in the prefetch directory. 
However, none of my .nfo text file are located in the list of the file to prefetch.
For example, in the prefetch file associated with Internet Explorer, you can see that its temporary files such as pictures are listed in the prefetch file. 
I believe that if I could force my file to appear in that list; the open/read operations on them would be faster as Windows would already know where they are 
locted on the disk.

Why aren't my files located in the .pf prefetch file along with my DLL? 
What is the condition for a file to appear in a prefetch file?

Does this make sense?

I was also wondering if there is a way to force Windows XP to pre-fetch a full directory or a list of files?

This is an already commercialised product that is sold with a computer. Therefore, we have full access to tweak the OS. 
However, we have not plan to do extrem alteration to our application.

Regards

Comment: How is the application being launched? Are you manually running it or is it part of the startup group, registry, or etc? I'm not sure which version of the OS but some "Sandbox" startup programs to help with startup time because so many vendors want their programs to start at the same time.

Comment: Usually the user manually starts the application! We are working on automatic launch but I don't see how it could help..

Comment: By basic function from std you mean ifstream objects? Plain C functions are supposed to have much better performance when processing large amount of text..

Comment: No, automatic launch would actually hurt it if I remember correctly. I can't seem to find where I found that article. Certain versions of windows set automatically started programs at lower priority to allow the windows UI to be responsive faster. I don't believe it applies if you are starting it manually so disregard my comments.

Comment: Here it is not about the processing power of the std function since at the second launch; it takes literally 10 second instead of 10 minutes to launch the files!
I believe that it is more about the hard drive cache..

Comment: Is the system idle when you launch or still busy?  Some of my XP drone machines from a previous job took much longer to get to an idle state after boot than others.  There was no rhyme or reason to it that I could find.  I am glad I don't have to work on it anymore...

Answer (score 4):

IMO, if you're reading >20000 files at startup, that's definitely a problem with the application.
Why anyone would prefer tweaking the OS to actually fixing their application is beyond me.

If it takes 10 minutes for >20000 files, you're looking at <30 ms per file, which isn't *that* bad for a rotating disk, especially if you're using the standard C++ file routines, which have quite a bit of overhead, IIRC.

When it takes 10 seconds (0.5 ms per file) that's because the files are already in the system disk cache.

Even if you got it working, the prefetching doesn't magically make things faster; the OS  would still have to seek, open, read, and close >20000 files, which *will* take in the order of minutes.

The best way to improve your load time is to bundle the files together and read them all at once.
For maximum efficency, stick them in a compressed archive.
Or use SSDs.